# Cannot animate UIImage with timing delay in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

I am attempting to animate the alpha of a UIImage after 3 seconds has passed. By default the alpha is set to 0 and after 3 seconds, the alpha should change to 1, thus displaying the image to the user. My code I wrote for my animation does set the alpha to 0, but I am unable to change the the alpha to 1 after 3 seconds. I am newer to swift and not sure where I am going wrong with this. Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeOneViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var swipeImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    swipeImageView.alpha = 0
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    displaySwipeView()
}

func displaySwipeView() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.swipeImageView.alpha = 1
        }

    }, completion: nil)
}

}
```

Comment: If you want your animation should complete in 3 second then withDuration: 1.0, should be withDuration: 3.0,

Comment: I want the animation to begin after a 3 second delay, not take 3 seconds to complete.

Comment: From where are you calling this method ? Make sure it is view will appear not view did load and also try in main queue

Comment: I am calling the function in viewDidAppear with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this code:

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeOneViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var swipeImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        swipeImageView.alpha = 0
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        displaySwipeView()
    }

    func displaySwipeView() {
        swipeImageView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.swipeImageView.alpha = 1
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick. The image is still visible immediately when the view loads.

Comment: @AndrewTuzsonhow about now?

Comment: That did the trick! However, now the image is visible for a split second before it disappears. How do I overcome that?

Comment: Would I use swipeImageView.alpha = 0 in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @AndrewTuzson that means that somewhere between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` you are setting `swipeImageView.alpha` to 1 again.. try putting `swipeImageView.alpha = 0` to `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it on main queue like this:

```
func displaySwipeView() {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 3.0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

   DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.swipeImageView.alpha = 1
   }

  }, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks! I copied over your syntax and called displaySwipeView() in viewDidLoad() after setting the alpha to 0. The image is now visible when the screen loads. Any ideas?

Comment: So the problem now is, if I'm right, that image loads but without animation?

Comment: That is correct. The image is displayed immediately when the view is loaded. I have updated the syntax in the original post.

Comment: putting it on the main thread is useless.. viewDidLoad is executed on the main thread already

Comment: @AndrewTuzson Try using any other UIViewAnimationOptions. Other than **.beginFromCurrentState** try using **.curveEaseInOut**. **beginFromCurrentState** sometimes shows unexpected behaviour.

Comment: is there any other code that you're using on swipeImageView. Just tried out on device and simulator. Animated after 3 seconds with and without the main Queue.